# What Is the Return Value of strcspn() When Str1 Does not Contain Str2?

Tags: c, string

I can't seem to find this anywhere, but does strcspn() return -1 when str1 does not contain str2? For example, say I have:

```
strcspn(argv[1], " ");
```

Will the function return -1 or something else if argv[1] does not contain a space?

Comment: Just a note: `strcspn` returns a `size_t`, which is an unsigned type, so it cannot return `-1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [strcspn reference on cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/)

```
strcspn(str1, str2)
```

> **returns**
>
> The length of the initial part of str1 not containing any of the characters that are part of str2.
>   This is the length of str1 if none of the characters in str2 are found in str1.

So your call `strcspn(argv[1], " ");` should return the length of `argv[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Tim. I definitely should've included that.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The function keeps on checking the character match for every character present in str1 till the end of string or a match found. In case there is no match, the end of string (position of null character ) is returned.